# VS Code runs python x2-3 slower than IDLE

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I open a simple txt file of 16mb to display a graph with mplotlib. Running the python file in IDLE takes 7sec to display the chart. In VS Code it takes 17sec. With a 55mb file it takes 17sec and 53sec respectively.

Why is VS Code slower, and how can I get similar speed as IDLE?

Code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time as time

time, v_out, v_in = np.loadtxt('PS_SIM.txt', unpack=True, skiprows=1)

plt.plot(time, v_out, label="Vout")

#Set legends
plt.legend(loc=8)
plt.grid()
plt.xlabel("Time [s]")
plt.ylabel("V_out [V]")
plt.suptitle("V_out")

#Set scales
plt.ylim(0.95, 1.05)
plt.yticks(np.arange(0.95,1.05, step=0.01))
plt.xlim(0.0085, 0.010)

#Show plot
plt.show()
```

settings.json:

```
{
    "python.pythonPath": "C:\\Users\\<..>\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36-32\\python.exe"
}
```

task.json:

```
    "version": "2.0.0",
"tasks": [
    {
        "label": "build",
        "type": "shell",
        "command": "msbuild",
        "args": [
            // Ask msbuild to generate full paths for file names.
            "/property:GenerateFullPaths=true",
            "/t:build"
        ],
        "group": "build",
        "presentation": {
            // Reveal the output only if unrecognized errors occur.
            "reveal": "silent"
        },
        // Use the standard MS compiler pattern to detect errors, warnings and infos
        "problemMatcher": "$msCompile"
    }
]
```

launch.json:

```
 "version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Python: Current File (Integrated Terminal)",
        "type": "python",
        "request": "launch", 
        "program": "${file}",
        "console": "integratedTerminal"
    },
...
```

Comment: Does your code have a lot of console output? Might be the VSCode terminal is the bottleneck

Comment: no console output (added the code above).

Answer (score 1):

Idle and VS Code are probably using different Python interpreters when they execute the code. When you run a Python program from within an IDE like VS Code it will use whatever  interpreter you have specified in the settings of that IDE. I'm guessing Idle uses whatever is the standard Python interpreter as it's not really an IDE

Comment: Understood, but it's not very helpful without advice on how to change that interpreter, and which may perform as desired.

Comment: Assuming you have the Python Extention installed, you can see the available interpreters if you click in the status bar (bottom left) on the one you're currently using. I doubt you have more than one without knowing, but it might be vscode is using python2 instead of 3?

Comment: Ok, I misunderstood 'interpreter'. They should both use the same (python.exe 3.6.4 32bit), hence why I specified it in settings.json.